# In customer portal, automatically log user into to external sites

Tags: customer-portal

In a customer portal, is it possible to have the user automatically signed in to external sites (outside of Salesforce) to which they've been granted access after the initial sign in?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe the concept you're referencing is [Single Sign-On (SSO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) - though it is unclear if you're referring to SSO as it relates to Salesforce that is:

- **[Inbound](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_about.htm&language=en_US)** (meaning the authentication is done before reaching Salesforce)
- **[Outbound within Salesforce](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Salesforce_as_an_Identity_Provider_for_Customer_Portal)** (meaning Saleforce is the centralized authentication server, and all the services are within Salesforce)
- **[Outbound outside of Saleforce](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_OAuth_to_Authorize_External_Applications)** (meaning Saleforce is the centralized authentication server, and all the services are outside Salesforce)
- **Neither** (meaning Salesforce is not involved in the process)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I believe what I'm interested in implementing is what you're calling SSO outbound - is this the same thing as Federated Authentication using SAML? I've read a few documents and watched a few videos but it's still unclear to me how such a system would be implemented.

Comment: @Ryan: Updated the post, the words "Inbound" & "Outbound" now link to additional information. Let me know if this answers your question, thanks!

Comment: Thank you. It looks like the inbound description most closely fits what I'd like to do (implement SSO in a customer portal with "apps" linking to external sites). Within that category, it seems as though "Federated Authentication using SAML" is what needs to be implemented. My apologies for not coming up with a specific question about, but I'm still not sure even after reading the documentation how one would go about implementing such a system, or even how the system works in a general sense. Any general information on this topic or specific tips regarding implementation would be appreciated.

Comment: (Here's one specific question: how would one integrate the service provided at http://axiomsso.herokuapp.com/SamlIdpHome.action into a federated authentication using SAML implementation?)

Comment: @Ryan: If you have new questions, you need to ask a new question; meaning it is one thing to clarify a question, and completely different to change a generic question into a specific how-to. My suggestion would be that instead of generalizing the topic like you did in this question, to clearly stay the exact context and the outcome needed. In response to the question related to Axiom SSO, that service, based on my understanding is only used to gain access to Salesforce using after the user auths on a 3rd party site; meaning aside from giving the okay to access Salesforce, nothing else is done.